# Accessing a method in an existing instance of a class from AppDelegate

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I need to pass some data that I grab when the app comes back into the foreground, I have managed to trigger the method but I can't figure out how to trigger it in the existing instance of my ViewController rather than making a new instance.

Map.cs

```
 public delegate void beginRefreshMapLine(ReturnRouteTaken returnRouteTaken);

  public void updateRouteList(ReturnRouteTaken returnRouteData)
    {
        coordList = new List<CLLocationCoordinate2D>();
        foreach(GPSData point in returnRouteData.GPSData)
        {
            coordList.Add(new CLLocationCoordinate2D { Latitude = double.Parse(point.Lat), Longitude = double.Parse(point.Lng) });

            updateMap(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }
```

this is the method I need to trigger in the current instance from AppDelegate.cs

AppDelegate.cs

```
if (GlobalVar.BoolForKey("trackMe"))
        {
            ReturnRouteTaken returnRouteData = webtools.GetRouteTaken(new ReturnRouteTaken() { TestDriveID = GlobalVar.IntForKey("routeTrackedID") });
            if (returnRouteData.GPSData.Count > 0)
            {

            }
        }
```

Here is where I am stuck, I have tried looking into delegates and invoking the method that way but I cannot get my head around how to implement it. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all the application's ViewControllers in iOS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757639/how-to-get-all-the-applications-viewcontrollers-in-ios)

Comment: I added a Swift answer before I realised you were asking about c#. Anyway, look at having your view controller subscribe to the UIapplicationWillEnterForeground notification

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I flagged this as a possible [dupe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14757639/how-to-get-all-the-applications-viewcontrollers-in-ios), but that thread is in Obj-C, however the same concept can easily be applied using Xamarin.iOS.

Just create a Singleton class with an `array` or `List` of `UIViewControllers` as a property in that class and every time you instantiate a new ViewController, add it to the `array` or`List`, but also make sure you remove a view controller from the `array` or `List` when the view controller is disposed.

e.g. your singleton could look like:

```
public class ViewControllerHolder
{
    // make constructor private to force use of Instance property
    // to create and get the instance.
    private ViewControllerHolder()
    {
    }

    private static ViewControllerHolder _instance;
    public static ViewControllerHolder Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (_instance == null)
            {
                _instance = new ViewControllerHolder();
                _instance.Controllers = new List<UIViewController>();
            }
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    public List<UIViewController> Controllers { get; private set; }

}
```

And then you can always get access to your `List` of view controllers with `ViewControllerHolder.Instance.Controllers` and perform any add or remove operations on it.

And if you are really only interested in the one view controller, then just add that one to the `List` when instantiated, but do remove it when the view controller is no longer needed so you don't try to access a disposed view controller and also so that the view controller can be garbage collected when it is no longer in use.

Comment: Oh wow, I never thought of this, this is a really cool idea, let me have a go and I will get back to you

Comment: Well it didn't crash! which is promising. I need to go for a drive to test it, will update and accept if it works, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Creating a singleton array that holds all the living `UIViewController`s works, personally I like to keep things decoupled as much as I can and do not like holding and maintaining a list of objects for no real reason...

You can pass data around via:

- Selector
- NoticationCenter

In any `UIViewController` that you need to "talk" to, you can subscribe to notifications and/or register `Selector`s.

In your `UIViewController` register for which Notifications you wish to receive...

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(this, new Selector(Const.StartRefresh), new NSString(Const.StartRefresh), null);
}
```

Still in your `UIViewController`, implement the selector that the notification center will perform a `send_msg` to:

```
[Export(Const.StartRefresh)]
void LocalStartRefresh(NSNotification notification)
{
    if (notification.Name == Const.StartRefresh)
        Console.WriteLine("StartRefresh from NotificationCenter:" + notification.Object);
}
```

In your `UIApplicationDelegate`, use the notification center to publish a new `NSNotification` to every active `UIViewController` that has subscribed:

```
public override void WillEnterForeground(UIApplication application)
{
    NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.PostNotificationName(Const.StartRefresh, new NSString("some custom data"));
}
```

**Or**, skip notifications and directly invoke the `Selector`:

In your `UIViewController`, implement the selector/method to call:

```
[Export(Const.StopRefresh)]
void LocalStopRefresh()
{
    Console.WriteLine("StopRefresh from Selector");
}
```

In your `UIApplicationDelegate`, send an action to **all** instanced view controller instances that accept this `Selector`:

```
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
{
    var vc = UIApplication.SharedApplication?.KeyWindow?.RootViewController;
    while (vc != null)
    {
        if (vc.RespondsToSelector(new Selector(Const.StopRefresh)))
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.SendAction(new Selector(Const.StopRefresh), vc, this, new UIEvent());
        vc = vc.PresentedViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is really a better answer than mine. :-)

Comment: @jgoldberger Not such "better", but "different", I've seen the singleton array of ViewControllers approach done many times and it is a valid style, It really depends upon your programming "style" I guess. I prefer "eventing and subscribing" either through the `NSNotificationCenter` (or writing custom C# Event if needed), as is uses the existing iOS framework (or DotNet framework) as it was designed to be used... but again, there are many ways to skin that cat ;-) It also works well in an MVVM or VIPER approach.

Comment: I always forget about NSNotificationCenter (except when needed to get system notifications like for the keyboard appearing, etc) or just testing for RespondsToSelector. I like your "style" better. :-)